# ¿Obtener la diferencia en horas de dos DateTime Java Server Faces?

Tags: java, mysql

Buenos dias mi consulta es la siguiente en dos Datetime capturo una fecha de inicio y una fecha final, al momento de guardar mi fecha final en la base de datos necesito que me guarde un dato de tipo Float con la diferencia de esas dos fechas en horas hago una comparacion pero siempre ne arroja el mismo resultado -1.

```
 public void botonTerminarTiempo() {

    tiempos.setFechaHoraFinal(fechaActual);
    tiemposFacade.edit(tiempos);
    Date fechaInicial = tiempos.getFechaHoraInicio();
    Date fechaFinal = tiempos.getFechaHoraFinal();
    Integer resultadoFecha;
    resultadoFecha = fechaInicial.compareTo(fechaFinal);
    tiempos.setTotalHoraHombre(resultadoFecha.floatValue());
    tiemposFacade.edit(tiempos);


    fechaActual = new Date();
    laborSeleccionada = new Labor();
    lineaSeleccionada = new Linea();
    operarioSeleccionado = new Operarios();
    ordentrabajo = new Ordentrabajo();
    tiempos = new Tiempos();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método compareTo que estás utilizando no sirve para restr fechas, sirve para compararlas.
Este método devuelve -1, 0 o 1 dependiendo si una fecha es mayor que la otra, igual o menor.

Si quieres hallar la diferencia entre dos fechas, lo que tienes que hacer es restarlas de esta manera:

```
long diferenciaEn_ms = fechaFinal.getTime() – fechaInicial.getTime();
```

La diferencia la vas a obtener en un tipo de variable long, así que si lo necesitas en un Float sólo te queda convertirlo.

Comment: Y la diferencia es el número de milisegundos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me genero Información:   Diferencia-7.9462568E7 este resultado  de casualidad no sabras como transfoirmarlo en horas.

Comment: Como bien te ha dicho @SJuan76, la diferencia que te resulta es en milisegundos, así que para obtener el resultado en horas tienes que dividir por 1000 para pasarlo a segundos, después por 60 para pasarlo a minutos y después por 60 para tenerlo en horas.