# Es posible guardar valores extra de una consulta sql en java?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, h2

Actualmente me encuentro buscando como puedo calcular la diferencia de horas frente una de inicio y una final, por lo cual debo restar esta ultima con la de inicio, pero como es un valor extra que no existe en mi tabla, no la puedo tomar en mi proyecto java, por lo cual quisiera saber si existe alguna forma de hacerlo sin necesidad de implementar más código de lo necesario....

Mi sentencia SQL es la siguiente

`SELECT *, DATEDIFF(hour,horaInicio,horaFinal) AS hours FROM tech WHERE idTech=? AND (WEEK(horaInicio)=? AND WEEK(horaFinal)=?)`

El valor que deseo retornar o darle uso son la diferencia de horas frente la inicial y la final, que al aplicar sql puro, me retornaria otra columna, pero la verdad quiero obtener esa información y realizar unas operaciones desde mi backend java, con el framework de spring boot.

**He pensado en varias opciones, donde la primera es modificar y agregar más atributos a la clase donde almaceno o la otra posible sería crear una subclase y por medio de esta realizar el almacenamiento de la consulta que deseo.**

El objetivo que tengo es mostrar una columna extra sin necesidad de implementar más codigo.

Esta es mi tabla.

```
`id` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `idTech` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `idService` VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `horaInicio` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    `horaFinal` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

[image: Esto lo es lo que me devuelve la sentencia.]

[image: Este es mi modelo]

[image: Mi clase de repositorio]
[image: Repositorio]
[image: Repo]

Comment: La verdad no vale la pena, porque las consultas en una base de datos se ejecutan cerca de 100 veces más rápido ya que están altamente optimizadas, especialmente es el caso de h2 al ser una BDD en memoria. ( Además de que si quieres código en Java pon código en Java )

Comment: Claro, te entiendo, pero la cuestion es la siguiente, deseo calcular cuantas horas hay de diferencia y del mismo modo poder mostrarlas, porque logico, la consulta que hago es rapida y me evitaria de implementar mas lineas de codigo. Pero la verdad no se como mostrar esos valores al momento de consumir la api.

Comment: Todo tu planteamiento no hace a la pregunta basada en opiniones?

Comment: De hecho no, lo unico que deseo es conocer la diferencia de horas y mostrarla en angular al momento de consumir esta api.@gbianchi

Comment: Entonces cual es la relevancia de la consulta en tu [mcve]?

Comment: Pues mira, la consulta desde java solo muestra las variables que tengo diseñadas en la tabla cierto, entonces quiero saber si es posible mostrar esa columna extra donde hago el calculo de diferencia de horas, por qué tu que recomendarías? @RuslanLópez

Comment: De hecho, que preguntes como te conviene diseñar la solucion la hace basada en opiniones.. Si tu orm no te permite crear un objeto aunque sea temporal con un campo mas, entonces en mi opinion tu orm no sirve...

Comment: Si no quieres agregar otro atributo a la clase simplemente agrega el método para [calcular la diferencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/100828).

Comment: No hago uso de orm, porque estoy haciendo uso de sql puro, porque si fuera en orm, fuera mas sencillo el tomar el nuevo dato, pero no se como implementar para que me salga de esa forma. @gbianchi

Comment: Ok, tratare de implementar de esa manera. Aunque no saben si exista otra forma mas directa. @Sal

Comment: Sql no tiene nada que ver con que uses o no un orm. Hay muchos orm que te permiten solo usar la parte de mapeo contra sql puro. Por eso preguntaba

Comment: Ah si, si llegas a mapear es otra cosa, porque segun tengo entendido, no se si me equivoque, para eso se usa el NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. @gbianchi

Comment: me referia a mapear tu consulta a tus objetos, no mapear tus parametros de la consulta. Cuando haces el query, vos lo bajas a un objeto automaticamente usando spring? tus clases POCO solo tienen los mismos campos que los objetos? algo te impide crear otra clase POCO que es la que vas a mandar a otra parte de tu sistema?

Comment: Ya te agrego mas informacion, disculpa, la verdad soy nuevo con el uso del framework, pero si me podrias dar alguna idea estaria muy agradecido.